# Make bulma columns occupy complete vertical space

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bulma

I am using Bulma columns & have divided my columns to `column is-2` and `column is-10`. I am using `column is-2` to show a vertical navigation bar using Bulma Menu component.

After adding background-colour to my menu, I saw that my component doesn't stretch to the complete page vertically.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: post your code please with snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Make the navigation column's height 100vh and sticky.